# Python BeautifulSoup double question mark in xml definition

Tags: python, xml, xhtml, beautifulsoup

I thought it must be a bug so i issued a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/984258). 
On the other hand i might be missing something so i need another look on the code.

The problem is, when i initialize BeautifulSoup with contents of an .xhtml file, xml definition gets two question marks at the end of it.

Can you reproduce the problem? Is there a way to avoid it? Am i missing a function, a method, an argument or something?

**Edit0:** It's BeautifulSoup 4 on python 2.x.

**Edit1:** Why downvote?

---

The problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"??>
```

Terminal Output:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> with open('example.xhtml', 'r') as f:
...     txt = f.read()
...     soup = bs(txt)
... 
>>> print txt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

>>> print soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"??>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at examples in [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it looks like they may have an issue with it: "`BeautifulSoup("<a><b /></a>", "xml")` -> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">...`": it's missing the closing `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I've committed a fix which will be in the next release of Beautiful Soup.

[The root cause:](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParser.handle_pi)

> The HTMLParser class uses the SGML syntactic rules for processing instructions. An XHTML processing instruction using the trailing '?' will cause the '?' to be included in data.

In general, you'll have better results parsing XHTML with the "xml" parser, as ThiefMaster suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I'll install lxml parser or get the src from bzr.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an XML parser:

```
soup = bs(txt, 'xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your contents of variable in 'txt' in an example.xhtml file I can't reproduce the issue with Python2.7 and the corrosponding BeautifulSoup module (not bs4). Works fine and dandy for me.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(txt)
>>> print soup
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the issue you are encountering with it, as in what is your end aim, maybe then somoone can suggest a workaround

Comment: As soon as you're not using the same software, saying that you can't reproduce it is useless.

Comment: I completely agree with you coming from that perspective. I merely wanted to suggest that if the option is available, consider using the 2.7 varient.

Comment: It's all about BeautifulSoup 4, but thank you for mentioning that.